# Lazarus IDE not correctly installable from repository in Mint 18.x

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, ide

I am on Linux Mint 18.x Cinnamon 64-bit.

I need Lazarus IDE. There are multiple related packages. The main ones are:

```
fpc
fpc-src
lazarus
```

Man needs all these three for it to work. So I tried a week ago, and today again, to install these from repository. Ending up with an error while configuring multiple related packages.

> fpc - the Compiler, some command line tools, base units and non visual components like database access
>
> fpc-src - the sources of fpc and its packages, needed for code browsing
>
> lazarus - the IDE, visual components and help files

**EDIT:**

In the official repository, there is an old version 1.6.x and I want the current version, which to date is 1.8.0, released on December 06, 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Updated for the latest versions: Lazarus 1.8.0 and FPC 3.0.4.

---

First off, you need to purge the packages already installed from the official repository:

```
sudo apt-get purge fpc fpc-src lazarus
```

And purge all related packages, if there are any:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
```

---

We will not be installing the packages from repository, it just does not work, we have to download it over secure connection from [sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/Lazarus%201.8.0/).

Once you have downloaded these 3 files:

1. FPC Compiler:

   ```
   fpc_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. FPC Sources:

   ```
   fpc-src_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Lazarus IDE:

   ```
   lazarus-project_1.8.0-0_amd64.deb
   ```

Before installation, you need to check their [hashes](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/index.php?page=checksums#1_8_0), they need to match:

1. FPC Compiler:

   ```
   sha256sum fpc_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb
   ```

   > ```
   > e025e13e6b7bd415d3bcc6da5e9004448b0ce593195082acd5aa1843394e1a34
   > ```
2. FPC Sources:

   ```
   sha256sum fpc-src_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb
   ```

   > ```
   > cdf49f0074cbb20c096de1fa71f6430883f084d71e200e63aecd8f77672e5e89
   > ```
3. Lazarus IDE:

   ```
   sha256sum lazarus-project_1.8.0-0_amd64.deb
   ```

   > ```
   > 62024510514c2f6e16d50c1cae11c9e0329e91beecf35e5e8e5a09c43f2cdde8
   > ```

After checking the hash sums, either click on each package and install them in GUI, or do it from terminal:

1. FPC Compiler:

   ```
   sudo apt install ./fpc_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb
   ```
2. FPC Sources:

   ```
   sudo apt install ./fpc-src_3.0.4-1_amd64.deb
   ```
3. Lazarus IDE:

   ```
   sudo apt install ./lazarus-project_1.8.0-0_amd64.deb
   ```

Finally, you need to prevent upgrading of these packages, i.e. to hold these packages, because it might break otherwise in the future:

```
sudo apt-mark hold fpc fpc-src lazarus lazarus-project
```

Answer (score -1):

When I upgraded to Mint 18 (Sarah), Lazarus quit working.
The Lazarus/1.6 directory was not installed, and multiple times was unable to get it to install correctly, it should be in `/usr/share/lazarus/1.6/`. This is a problem with the program manager and the package itself.

Here is what fixed the problem for me:

I went into Synaptic package manager, and using the filter (keywords: `lazarus` and `fp`, I deleted all packages related to Lazarus and Free Pascal. With the `fp` filter, I deleted all `fpc`* and `fp`* files related to Free Pascal.

I downloaded the 3 needed files from [Sourceforge, version 1.6 64-bit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Linux%20amd64%20DEB/Lazarus%201.6/).

I installed the files in this order:

```
fpc

fpc-src

lazarus
```

Note: since my system is 64-bit, the link provided is to the `amd64` files.
For 32-bit, you will need the `i386` files.